# How to insert, through VBA, a formula in a cell with special characters like "-" or "$"?

Tags: excel, vba, cell, formula

I searched on internet, without any help coming out of that...
I simply would like to be able to have my VBA code to write this formula in a cell :

`=IF(C4="-"; "-"; Cars!C4*C4*Data!$C$8)`

As you guessed, there is a page called "Cars" and one called "Data" where I pick the informations needed.

Of course, as it is a VBA code, the C4 will be 2 variables, one for the C and one for the 4 that will evolve...
Actually, I tried this :

`Worksheets("Calculation").Range(Column & PosStartCalc + 1).Formula = "=" & "IF(" & Column & PosStartCalc & " = " & "" - "" & ";" & " - " & ";" & "Cars!" & Column & PosStart & "*" & Column & PosStartCalc & "*" & "Data!" & "C" & "8" & ")"`

(The variable Column contains the column letter and the variable PosStartCalc contains the row number)

This hurts my eyes and apparently VBA's ones too as it gives the error "Run-Time error '13': Type Mismatch'
Could anyone tell me how to do that?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You dont always use `PosStartCalc` at one point you use `PosStart`. Is that intended? To avoid typos in variables start your codes with: `Option Explicit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, assuming the column variable is a string and row a long variable. I might not have all the variables right, but you'll be able to get what I meant to do here.

```
Sub test()

Dim Col As String: Col = "C"
Dim Rw As Long: Rw = 4

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Calculation")
    Debug.Print "=IF(" & Col & Rw & "=""-"",""-"",Cars!" & Col & Rw & "*" & Col & Rw & "*Data!$C$8)"
    .Cells(Rw + 1, Col).Formula = "=IF(" & Col & Rw & "=""-"",""-"",Cars!" & Col & Rw & "*" & Col & Rw & "*Data!$C$8)"
End With

End Sub
```

So what you might forget easily is to use the `,` as parameter delimiter in a VBA programmed formula. When you put this on your sheet Excel will automatically replace that with the appropriate delimiter for your region.

Another thing to keep in mind; whenever you about to use a string value in such an function, don't forget to wrap it in double quotes!

[image]

Don't forget to remove the `Debug.print ....` line. It was merely there to show the output :)

Comment: I tried it, it give me the error "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object defined error"... I don't even know what that can mean -_-

Comment: @zepeu, as you see in the screenshot, it works for me. Have you tried my code inside some other module? Try to use it seperately and check the outcome.

Comment: Ok, that works... But I have absolutely no idea of what's happening in this code... can you give a small explanation, please? I'll neeed to reuse this and adapt it, so, better to understand it ;-) What are these .address(false, false)? Where did the ; disappear? How does this works?

Comment: @zepeu, I removed the use of `Address`, it wasn't neccessary and if you unfamiliar with the code it would overcomplicate things. Now I just used a string and long variable. The `;`, or semi-colon, is your region's paramter delimiter when you create formulas within the worksheet. Though when working through VBA the standard delimiters are the EN-us ones, thus a comma. This will automatically be translated by VBA when you use the code on the sheet.

Comment: Ah, I just noticed your last line saying to get rid of the "debug" line... It make way more sense now :p Thank's a lot !