# How to add a Dollar $ sign to a complex formula?

Tags: excel, vba, formula, dollar-sign

I already asked several questions for this code I'm writing for work, and in another post ( here : [How to insert, through VBA, a formula in a cell with special characters like "-" or "$"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57427885/how-to-insert-through-vba-a-formula-in-a-cell-with-special-characters-like) ), JvdV gave me that formula :

```
With Worksheets(LabourSheet)
    .Cells(PosStartLineCalc + 1, PosStartColumnLt).Formula = "=IF(or(" & .Cells(PosStartLineCalc, PosStartColumnLt).Address(False, False) & "=""-""," & .Cells(PosStartLineCalc, PosStartColumnLt).Address(False, False) & "=""X""),""-"",Cars!" & .Cells(PosStartLine + (TPICode * 3) - 3, Split(Cells(1, col).Address, "$")(1)).Address(False, False) & "*" & .Cells(PosStartLineCalc, PosStartColumnLt).Address(False, False) & "*Data!$C$8)"
End With
```

Which once in the cells give, for example : =IF(OR(C4="-";C4="X");"-";Cars!C4*C4*Data!$C$8)

No surprise if I tell you that I don't understand the VBA side fully...

Anyway, it works, but I would need to add some "$" dollar signs as I copy past the whole table and the "Cars!C4" should stay as it is...

So, how to add nice dollar signs on the "Cars!C4" to become "Cars!$C$4"?

I tried it this way :

",Cars!" & .Cells(**"$" &** PosStartLine + (TPICode * 3) - 3, **"$" &** 
Split(Cells(1, col).Address, "$")(1)).Address(False, False)

",Cars!" & .Cells(**""$"" &** PosStartLine + (TPICode * 3) - 3, **""$"" &** 
Split(Cells(1, col).Address, "$")(1)).Address(False, False)

",Cars!" & .Cells(**chr(36) &** PosStartLine + (TPICode * 3) - 3, **chr(36) &** 
Split(Cells(1, col).Address, "$")(1)).Address(False, False)

it gives me a "type mismatch" error :'(

Nothing worked...

I searched on internet, of course, but I always find pages where they explain that you can press F4 and for what the dollar signs are...

Thank's by advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.Cells(PosStartLine + (TPICode * 3) - 3, Split(Cells(1, col).Address, "$")(1)).Address(False, False)
```

In this piece of code, change the arguments given to .address to (True,True)

```
.Cells(PosStartLine + (TPICode * 3) - 3, Split(Cells(1, col).Address, "$")(1)).Address(**True, True**)
```

Comment: Ah? It's that simple? Thank's :D

Answer (score 1):

You've specified `.Address(False, False)` The `False` statements are for `RowAbsolute` and `ColumnAbsolute` Changing these to `True` where applicable will give you the dollar signs for an absolute cell reference instead of relative

e.g.

```
With Worksheets(LabourSheet)
    .Cells(PosStartLineCalc + 1, PosStartColumnLt).Formula = "=IF(or(" & .Cells(PosStartLineCalc, PosStartColumnLt).Address(False, False) & "=""-""," & .Cells(PosStartLineCalc, PosStartColumnLt).Address(False, False) & "=""X""),""-"",Cars!" & .Cells(PosStartLine + (TPICode * 3) - 3, Split(Cells(1, col).Address, "$")(1)).Address(True, True) & "*" & .Cells(PosStartLineCalc, PosStartColumnLt).Address(False, False) & "*Data!$C$8)"
End With
```

Comment: Thank's for the explanation :)

Comment: @zepeu Should add - the default value for these is `True` so you can just remove the brackets if you wish

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be possible to do this by simply adding dollar signs flanked by quotation marks in the formula like below:

```
"$"
```

Comment: Well, as you saw, the formula isn't written directly, I tried that, of course, it gives me an error... I'll edit my post to add what I tried, sorry for forgetting that ^^,