# Different ways of writing the same formula give different results?

Tags: excel, vba, formula, with-statement

I'm back with this formula I don't fully understand (but better than last time ;) [How to add a Dollar $ sign to a complex formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57727825/how-to-add-a-dollar-sign-to-a-complex-formula) ) and edited it to use it somewhere else...

My question is simple, I take the exact same formula, but depending on how I write it in the "with", it don't give the same result :(

My goal was to make a nice big "with" having the formula inserted in the cell, but also formatting the cell (color etc.)

I have these 2 ways of writing it :

the first one gives me the result I intend : `=AVERAGE('C Labour Rate'!c6:g6)`

and the second gives : `=AVERAGE('C Labour Rate'!E9:I9)`

```vb
With Worksheets(YearToFill) 
            .Cells(PosStartLine + (TPINb * 3) - 3, PosStartColumn + (ActiveColumn - 1)).Formula = "=AVERAGE('" & LabourSheet & "'!" & .Cells(PosStartLine + (TPINb * 3) - 1, PosStartColumn + (ActiveColumn - 1) * NbRepairCodes) _
            .Address(False, False) & ":" & .Cells(PosStartLine + (TPINb * 3) - 1, PosStartColumn + (ActiveColumn - 1) * NbRepairCodes + NbRepairCodes - 1).Address(False, False) & ")"
        End With
```

(this one gives `=AVERAGE('C Labour Rate'!C6:G6)` )

```vb
With Worksheets(YearToFill).Cells(PosStartLine + (TPINb * 3) - 3, PosStartColumn + (ActiveColumn - 1)) 'Formula for the average occurences of the TPI in Europe
            .Formula = "=AVERAGE('" & LabourSheet & "'!" & .Cells(PosStartLine + (TPINb * 3) - 1, PosStartColumn + (ActiveColumn - 1) * NbRepairCodes) _
            .Address(False, False) & ":" & .Cells(PosStartLine + (TPINb * 3) - 1, PosStartColumn + (ActiveColumn - 1) * NbRepairCodes + NbRepairCodes - 1).Address(False, False) & ")"
        End With
```

(This second one gives `=AVERAGE('C Labour Rate'!E9:I9)` )

What is happening in there? 
I even tried with the 2 formulas written down one after the other, and checking the result by running the code in step by step mode, it clearly don't have the same result...

I guess it's the ".cells" that makes the problems, but why? There is no "offset" or other function depending on the active cell...

I don't understand, and I didn't find help on the internet, mostly because I don't know how to search for that :'(

Thank's by advance for your help ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes since you are using the `.Cells` in the formula it is appending that onto the with:

First:

```
Worksheets(YearToFill).Cells(PosStartLine + (TPINb * 3) - 1, PosStartColumn + (ActiveColumn - 1) * NbRepairCodes + NbRepairCodes - 1).Address(False, False)
```

Second:

```
Worksheets(YearToFill).Cells(PosStartLine + (TPINb * 3) - 3, PosStartColumn + (ActiveColumn - 1)).Cells(PosStartLine + (TPINb * 3) - 1, PosStartColumn + (ActiveColumn - 1) * NbRepairCodes + NbRepairCodes - 1).Address(False, False)
```

Cells is relative to the parent:

> `Worksheets().Cells()`

Is relative to `A1`

But

> `Worksheets().Range("B10:B20").Cells(1,1).Address(0,0)`

Will return `B10` not `A1` thus offsetting the address.

Comment: Thank's for your reply, so, you mean the ```.Cells``` depends on the actually selected cell? Or just the range in which it is working? if I use your last line, but just before do a ```Worksheets().Range("B15").Activate```, the result of your line will be ```B15```?